# Injeção de dependência e acoplamento - quão errado isto esta?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Criei um projeto onde a intenção era ter uma arquitetura simples, um domínio rico e uma webApi, mas mal comecei e já to vendo as cagad*s, isto é muito ruim↓?

Então vamos la, criei um repositório genérico no meu domínio, implementei esse repositório na infra...

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    void Add (TEntity obj);
    TEntity Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    void Remove(TEntity obj);
    TEntity Update(TEntity obj);    
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas querendo economizar tempo... agora vem o que pra mim ta errado, resolvi que para cada entidade vou ter um serviço da seguinte forma:

```
public class DepartmentService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Department> Repository;
        public DepartmentService(IRepository<Department> repository)
        {
            Repository = repository;
        }

        public void AddDepartment(Department obj)
        {
            Repository.Add(obj);
        }
        public List<Department> AllDepartments()
        {
            return Repository.GetAll().ToList();
        }
    }
```

(É um serviço de domínio nele que vai ficar as regras de negocio)

Meu serviço recebe um repositório de um tipo (nesse caso Department) por injeção de dependência e no meu controller ta dessa forma:

```
public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
{

    private DepartmentService _Service;

    public DepartmentController(IRepository<Department> repository)
    {
        _Service = new DepartmentService(repository);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddDepartment(Department obj)
    {
        _Service.AddDepartment(obj);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>> GetAllDepartment()
    {

        return  _Service.AllDepartments();
    }

}
```

Como pode ser notado, eu instancio um serviço passando um repositório de tipo especifico, que estou recebendo por injeção de dependência....

E pra resolver isso no meu ConfigureServices usei o AddScoped:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Department>, Repository<Department>>();
```

Não queria gerar tanto acoplamento, mas na minha webApi tem dependência do domínio e da infra.

Isso que fiz ta muito ruim?

Comment: Isso é um desenho de CRUD simples, em uma modelagem Data Centric. Não é nem bom, nem ruim, é isso. Pode ser adequado ou não: esse é o ponto. É preciso entender o problema para compreender se essa é a melhor solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo um problema, algum acoplamento precisará ter. O importante é o domínio não ter a referencia nenhuma. Você poderia no caso, injetar também o DepartamentService e aplicar o UnitOfWork Pattern e separar o que é consulta do que é transacional (CQRS Pattern). Sempre tentando tirar o máximo de acoplamento do Controller.

Você pode conferir um exemplo de arquitetura limpa monolítica, porém utilizando princípios de padrões de projetos:

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

Ou usando DDD com microsservicos:

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers